# Delete all strings that do not contain any uppercase in Bash

Tags: bash, file, sed

I need to delete from a file all the words that do not contain any uppercase in bash.

I use the `sed` command but the output is the same as the input:

I tried `sed 's/[^0-9]*//' file`

Example input:

```
sjasd
ksaLK
asdn
Asdw
```

Output

```
ksaLK
Asdw
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your efforts in your post which you have put in order to solve your own problem. Please use CODE TAGS too to wrap your samples in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
sed -n '/[A-Z]/p'  Input_file
```

As per @PaulHodges's comment, once you are happy with results use `sed -i ....` option in above code to make changes in Input_file itself.

Comment: Doesn't actually delete from the file as OP asked, though it should be pretty easy to extrapolate from there. I like the simplicity of it, though.

Comment: @PaulHodges, sure thanks for letting know, added`sed -i` option in my solution now.

Comment: Now it is the `sed` who says `-ni`!

Answer (score 1):

To make a file without those:

```
grep '[A-Z]' infile > outfile
```

This is a nondestructive way to check first. Then you could replace the old file with the new one.

If you really want to edit the existing file in place:

```
sed -i '/[A-Z]/!d' infile
```

This says to delete all lines that do not have a capital letter.